# Concatenate string to comma separated string in c#

Tags: c#

I need to frame sql query and pass as value to SP for the comma separated values.

I need to add string at first and last to the comma separated values phrase.
How to remove and  for the last value
What is the best optimal approach?

```
string phrase = "2,3,4,5";
string[] words = phrase.Split(',');
StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
foreach (var word in words)
{ 
    sb.Append("Id = " + word +" and ") ;   
}
phrase = sb.ToString();
System.Console.Write(phrase);
```

Expected Output: Id= 2 OR Id= 3 OR Id= 4 OR Id=5

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. (side note: you probably want to use `OR` instead of `AND` - because  `Id = 2 AND Id =  3` will only be satisifed when `2==3`. which would mean the universe is broken.)

Comment: Nothing will match the query you've described. An `Id` cannot simultaneously be `2` **and** `3`. You probably want `OR`, not `AND`. But when you have a list of values like that, you can also use `IN`: `Id IN (2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you are right.. I need to add OR

Comment: @Andi Where did the phrase/value "2,3,4,5" originally come from? There might be an easier way of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you expand on the part where you said "pass as value to SP" ? Doing anything that looks like `EXEC mySproc '2,3,4,5'` is unlikely to work as you intend, unless the SP splits the value received

Comment: String.Join is sort of the opposite of string.Split

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this snippet. Just iterate over the array and handle the last value apart of the rest.

```
string phrase = "2,3,4,5";
string[] words = phrase.Split(',');
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
for (; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
{
     sb.Append("Id = " + words[i] +" or ");
}
sb.Append("Id = " + words[i]);
phrase = sb.ToString();
```